# Why it's work only for first button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I showing a list of items like this:

[image]

Why my code work only for first button? When I'm click to other one nothing happens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#js-toggle-attendance").click(function (e) {
        var button = $(e.target);
        $.post("/api/attendances", { gigId: button.attr("data-gig-id") }).done(function() {
            button.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info").text("Ide");
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("Coś poszło nie tak :(");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's by id `#js-toggle-attendance`. You need to use class and give it to each button

Comment: your code suggests there is only one button

Comment: show HTML for better help

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used same id in that button.... so can you change it to class?

#### ID Selector rule in jQuery

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
> one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
> will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
> should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
> element using the same ID is invalid.

Check on [DOC](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

#### PATCH in jQuery ID Selector

Using attribute selector you can select multiple element and bind event on all element. here I have passed attribute selector using [] not #id. **This is only patch for select maultiple element of same id not follow this at all**

```
 $("[id='js-toggle-attendance']").click(function (e) {
        var button = $(this);
        $.post("/api/attendances", { gigId: button.attr("data-gig-id") }).done(function() {
            button.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info").text("Ide");
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("Coś poszło nie tak :(");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have applied a `click` event on the element's `id`. As per [W3 rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) you can only use the element's `id` once. So change that `$("#js-toggle-attendance")` with something that used your class `$(".elementclass")`

Comment: `as per jQuery rule` - no, that's a HTML rule

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a single id on your buttons ?

Try something like this

```
function toggle (id){

    $.post("/api/attendances", { gigId: id }) //id=button.attr("data-gig-id") ????
                        .done(function() {
                             $("#js-toggle-attendance-"+id).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info").text("Ide");
                        })
                        .fail(function() {
                            alert("Coś poszło nie tak :(");
                        });
                });
}
```